# CSS that dynamically works with ngIf

Tags: html, css, angular

Using Angular 4, I have a div that I want horizontally aligned. This div has two spans within it that have `*ngIf` conditions. When one span is shown, the styling looks pretty good. When both are shown the text is primarily on the right side.

Is there a way to change the CSS used if one span is showing or when two spans are showing?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <div style="padding-left:42.5%;">
    <span *ngIf="items[i-1]?.date != item.date">{{item.date}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="items[i-1]?.time != item.time">{{item.time}}</span>
  </div>
  <ion-card">
    ...
  </ion-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with ng-template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `<div style="padding-left:42.5%;">` to `<div align="center">` was able to work for this situation.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <div align="center">
    <span *ngIf="items[i-1]?.date != item.date">{{item.date}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="items[i-1]?.time != item.time">{{item.time}}</span>
  </div>
  <ion-card">
    ...
  </ion-card>
</div>
```